# How to make loops start, break and start over again according to a variable?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to make a module that handle the health of a user.

If `self.hearts` are 0 the user dies, and it will print that out. 
But if the user is not dead and `self.hearts` are less than 10, the user will be healed every 20 seconds.

With this code below, the `monitor` function will only heal the user and won't print that the user is dead (especially when it happens). What am I doing wrong?

```
import threading

class Health(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hearts = 10

    def monitor(self):
        if self.hearts <= 10 and self.hearts > 0:
            def heal():
                threading.Timer(20.0, heal).start()
                if self.hearts < 10 and self.hearts > 0:
                    self.hearts += 1
                    print '+1 heart! :D'
                    print 'hearts %d' % self.hearts
            heal()
        elif self.hearts < 1:
            print 'You are dead'
            quit()

    def add(self, amount):
        if self.hearts < 10:
            self.hearts += amount
            print '+{} hearts! :D'.format(amount)
        else:
            print 'You are full of hearts'


    def remove(self, amount):
        self.hearts -= amount
        print '-{} hearts! :\'('.format(amount)


    def health(self):
        print 'Hearts: ', self.hearts


me = Health()
me.monitor()
```

I feel that I need I while loop but I don't know how to code it in the right way. I wish I knew how to code a loop that **starts, breaks and starts over again** according to `self.hearts`. This loop must *always wait for changes*.

How can I make the module prompts that the user is dead when it actually happens?

When I run it on the python console everything work except the 'You are dead' prompt:

```
>>> me.remove(5)
-5 hearts! :'(
>>> +1 heart! :D
hearts 6
me.remove(10)
-10 hearts! :'(
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this version of your code

i just noticed that you don't test for death with the timer try this version

```
def monitor(self):
    if self.hearts <= 20 and self.hearts > 0:
        def heal():
            if self.hearts < 10 and self.hearts > 0:
                self.hearts += 1
                print '+1 heart! :D'
                print 'hearts %d' % self.hearts
                threading.Timer(10.0, heal).start()
            elif self.hearts < 1:
                quit()
        heal()
```

you also need to make a test for death on delete to avoid waiting next timer check

```
def remove(self, amount):
        self.hearts -= amount
        print '-{} hearts! :\'('.format(amount)
        if self.hearts < 1:
            print 'You are dead'
```

Edited to avoid code repetition

Comment: still does not work

`>>> me.remove(5)
-5 hearts! :'(
>>> +1 heart! :D
hearts 6
me.remove(10)
-10 hearts! :'(
>>>`

Comment: So apparently the only way to achieve what I whit is to repeat the code, which I wanted to avoid :/

Answer (score 1):

You should save your timer object so you can call `cancel()` on it when `self.hearts` goes to zero.

So for example (in `heal()`):

```
self.healing_timer = threading.Timer(20.0, self.heal).start()
```

and in `remove()`:

```
def remove(self, amount):
    self.hearts -= amount
    print '-{} hearts! :\'('.format(amount)
    if self.hearts < 1:
        self.healing_timer.cancel()
        print 'You are dead'
```